how to make hugo use the last part of url string as parameter and not as a folder?
In hugo, i have a folder "/stock/caterpillar" and a url string "stock/caterpillar/tracks" where "tracks" should be a  parameter but hugo treats it as a page and therefore 404 error
my working url string is /stock/caterpillar/?subcat=tracks
i want it to be /stock/caterpillar/tracks
where "tracks" could be anything...
example: /stock/caterpillar/wheeled or /stock/caterpillar/excav
then in /caterpillar/single.html i can use whatever came after /stock/caterpillar/ just like it was /stock/caterpillar/?subcat=tracks which works perfectly... but i'd rather it be "/stock/caterpillar/tracks"
"tracks" should not the treated as a folder but a parameter i will use in the /stock/caterpillar/single.html page
at the moment im getting 404 because hugo says it cannot find the folder "tracks"

This requires URL rewriting by your web servers. Apache and nginx web servers handle this a bit differently. Please tell us more about your server setup.

server is on aws amplify... thanks

Since Hugo is a static site generator, I wonder if you are missing a list of possible subcat (sub-category?) options somewhere that would trigger Hugo to generate those pages. Could you include your code on how those pages are generated?

thanks for the reply... the sub-category pages are not created, i only have /stock/caterpillar/single.html... there's a javascript code within single.html that makes the api call to gather and display items based on subcat parameter in /?subcat=tracks (this works)... but im trying not to use url paramterers...  but instead a seo friendlier url like /stock/caterpillar/tracks where ill parse the last segment and pass that to the api... creating the folder/file is not an option because there could be hundreds of variations... so im having single.html (or list.html) do api calls to populate itself

ssg with next.js can do this approach smoothly, no problem... but im stuck with Hugo on this one :(

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
